# Graph traversing query returns no results

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher

I'm a bit confused by graph traversing queries. After executing:

```
CREATE (:Node {id: 0});
CREATE (:Node {id: 1});
CREATE (:Node {id: 2});
CREATE (:Node {id: 3});
MATCH (n:Node {id: 0}), (m:Node {id: 1})
CREATE (n)-[:LINK {date: "2023-03"}]->(m);
MATCH (n:Node {id: 1}), (m:Node {id: 2})
CREATE (n)-[:LINK {date: "2023-03"}]->(m);
MATCH (n:Node {id: 2}), (m:Node {id: 3})
CREATE (n)-[:LINK {date: "2023-03"}]->(m);
```

I want to find paths between Node with id 0 and Node with id 3, so I run next query:

```
MATCH p = (:Node {id:"0"})-[*]->(:Node {id: "3"})
RETURN p;
```

and this will return an empty set.
Isn't it supposed to return all paths between these two nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match on the integers 0 and 3, not the strings "0" and "3":

```
MATCH p = (:Node {id: 0})-[*]->(:Node {id: 3})
RETURN p;
```